# Athena Query JSON Fields Stored as String

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table which has a field

```
fields (string)
```

The data looks like

```
{"field_1":"value_1","field_2":"value_2"}
{"field_1":"value_3","field_2":"value_4"}
...
```

I would like to query such as:

```
select "fields"."field_1" as field_1 from table_name where field_1 = "something"
```

I have tried many methods and only either gotten an error or only empty values for field_1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to query like that: `"fields"."field_1"`? You can use json_parse as @Philipp suggested below and then extract the needed values with `json_extract_scalar(fields, '$.field_1')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the sample data it looks like fields is a JSON. So the first thing I would do is to use `json_parse` to convert it.

The syntax `"fields"."field_1"` would work for a `row` column - however, it looks like it's not possible to cast a json to a row in Athena (which is based on Presto 0.172) - see [Cast from JSON in the 0.172 Presto Release Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html).

You may convert it to a `map<varchar,varchar>` and then access it via [Subscript Operator](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html): `[]`

Example:

```
with example as
(
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        ('{"field_1":"value_1","field_2":"value_2"}'),
        ('{"field_1":"value_3","field_2":"value_4"}')
    ) AS t (fields)
)
,example_cast as
(
    select *
    ,cast(json_parse(fields) AS map<varchar,varchar>) fields_parsed
    from example 
)
select *
,fields_parsed['field_1'] fields_field_1
from example_cast;
```